# Rails 4 validates_associated on custom_context does not fail when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a custom validation context for a model with a has_many association. I believe I've set up the validations correctly, but the validation does not fail. Below are my models

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shifts
    validates_associated :shifts, on: :submit
end

class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :clock_in, on: :submit
end

r = Report.new
r.shifts << Shift.new(:name => "Nick")
r.valid?
 => true
r.valid?(:submit)
 => true #should be invalid since clock_in is blank still.
```

Is my syntax off? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the shift is beign added to the report? first print report after you add the shift, just to be sure.

and add this to your report model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :shifts, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

with this, validates_associated isn't necessary because the validation will be fired always on this cases.

Comment: In my real code, I do have accepts_nested_attributes_for but the error continued without it, so I took it out to keep the issue more "pure." Having certain validations run on the `:submit` context is key. To create, update a Report should be allowed to pass without the :submit context being valid, but when the report is going to be "submitted" all fields need to be validated. This feature of having custom contexts would be very useful but it doesn't seem to be behaving the way I expect.